# Is there a point to more than one design/tech specialist?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

Put differently, aside from unlocking the R&D and Tech labs, what do the "Design Specialist" and "Tech Specialist" trainings actually provide?

100 research points is kind of pricey to spend more than once if there's no additional benefit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making an employee the Tech or Design Specialist only allows you to make an *R&D and Hardware Lab*, nothing else. It is worth it though if you want to make your company bigger and get more money.

There is, however, no point to making more than one as it doesn't modify any stats.

Comment: Not what I asked -- I asked for the point to making *more than one* specialist.

Comment: No, there is no point.